# when I try to get admob in my app, My app get force close

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to add admob for my app for first time. I have read many information (including stackOverFlow). However I still have not got any luck. My app get force close.
Here is how I tried up to so far.

Androidmanifest.xml

I have added these lines within application tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And I aslo I added following line just before

```
<Meta-Data android:value="a14f9xxxxx(id from admob)" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"/>
```

attr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <declare-styleable name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView">            
       <attr name="backgroundColor" format="color" />
       <attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color" />
       <attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color" />
       <attr name="keywords" format="string" />
       <attr name="refreshInterval" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
  </resources>
```

frontpage.xml (layout for my frontpage activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/simple.stocktaketrial"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
...
some other layout and components here
...

<com.admob.android.ads.AdView     
       android:id="@+id/ad" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
       myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
       myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I added GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.0 in lib folder and built pass.

What I am doing wrong??

I have read the way of adding admob in xml in layout is better than adding codes to java. So if it is true I would like to keep it in the way.

Thanks you for your kind help in advance.

here is the logcat out put.

```
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{simple.stocktaketrial/simple.stocktaketrial.FrontPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #77: Error inflating class com.admob.android.ads.AdView
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #77: Error inflating class com.admob.android.ads.AdView
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at simple.stocktaketrial.FrontPage.onCreate(FrontPage.java:25)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    ... 11 more
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.admob.android.ads.AdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/simple.stocktaketrial-2.apk]
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
06-2 7 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
06-27 12:24:56.630: E/AndroidRuntime(25265):    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Do you have some LogCat output?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I did added to my post.

Comment: You are obviously new here to StackOverflow. Posting questions like this, you need to demonstrate the knowledge in what you've done,what was your research to the problem, what did you do to attempt fixing the problem, showing how much effort you've put in.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Yes I am new to here. I just did a bit more research on this error and found some one suggesting to rename the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.0 to GoogleAdMobAdsSdk and create libs folder rather than lib. Just have tried them but still no luck. Could you or anyone else have any idea or way to fix this error??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml and the incorrect case for 'Meta-Data'...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="...." android:versionCode=".." android:versionName="...">
   <application android:icon="...." android:label="....">
      <activity ..... >
      </activity>
      <meta-data android:value="a14f9xxxxx(id from admob)" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"/>
      <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

The above configChanges attribute is for Android SDK level 14 and above.

For lower, use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="...." android:versionCode=".." android:versionName="...">
   <application android:icon="...." android:label="....">
      <activity ..... >
      </activity>
      <meta-data android:value="a14f9xxxxx(id from admob)" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"/>
      <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The activity in there is within the Admobs library, no need to do anything extra :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By adding your extra line I get error.    error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|
 uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').  What I am missing here

Comment: That is within your application tag in the manifest right? What Android SDK version you're using? I just realized I have this targetting Android API SDK level 14.

Comment: no it in within manifest tag. How do I know Android SDK version do you mean it by API level for Android?? If so I am usign API level 8 since my phone got Android2.2

Comment: What I said was, it should be within the "<application...> // all activities declared here..</application>" Look at my edited answer to see what I am referring to!

Comment: Thanks not getting the error but still getting force close for my app.

Comment: it says this Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{simple.stocktaketrial/simple.stocktaketrial.FrontPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #77: Error inflating class com.admob.android.ads.AdView

Comment: The problem is within your android layout, you're using the wrong component identifier... its *com.google.ads.AdView*, not 'com.admob.android.ads.AdView'! and also, make sure you have the `ads:adUnitId="a14f9xxxxx(id from admob)"` attribute specified as well. :)

Comment: The clue is in the logcat - "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.admob.android.ads.AdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/simple.stocktaketrial-2.apk]"

Comment: Thanks for your time answering my question. But I have no idea what is the error causing by. Do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: This is my last answer to you because you are not reading it! I have said twice, read up ^^ in the comments...